# Permission denied when migrating in DigitalOcean

Tags: digital-ocean, phinx

I'm using the DigitalOcean terminal to try run a Phinx migration `vendor/bin/phinx migrate -e development` but I get the error "permission denied"

I have tried writing the command in different ways, I have made sure the data in my `phinx.php` is correct.

I'm really stuck, anyone have any experience with this?

Full Command:

```
root@webportal-project-name:/home/project/project-name# vendor/bin/phinx migrate -e development
```

Error:

> -bash: vendor/bin/phinx: Permission denied

Phinx.php:

```php
<?php

return
[
    'paths' => [
        'migrations' => '%%PHINX_CONFIG_DIR%%/db/migrations',
        'seeds' => '%%PHINX_CONFIG_DIR%%/db/seeds'
    ],
    'environments' => [
        'default_migration_table' => 'phinxlog',
        'default_environment' => 'development',
        'production' => [
            'adapter' => 'mysql',
            'host' => 'localhost',
            'name' => 'production_db',
            'user' => 'root',
            'pass' => '',
            'port' => '3306',
            'charset' => 'utf8',
        ],
        'development' => [
            'adapter' => 'mysql',
            'host' => 'localhost',
            'name' => 'customer_portal',
            'user' => 'root',
            'pass' => 'pK74He7NbqvNyFxz',
            'port' => '3306',
            'charset' => 'utf8',
        ],
        'testing' => [
            'adapter' => 'mysql',
            'host' => 'localhost',
            'name' => 'testing_db',
            'user' => 'root',
            'pass' => '',
            'port' => '3306',
            'charset' => 'utf8',
        ]
    ],
    'version_order' => 'creation'
];
```

Comment: What are the permissions on `vendor/bin/phinx`? Does it perhaps need to be run as `root`?

Comment: @underscore_d I'm kinda new to using phinx and digital ocean, how can I check the permissions ?

Comment: I mean the filesystem permissions, so for example do an `ls -Fal vendor/bin/phinx` to check which users/groups have permissions to the file. Or, if you're not using a Linux-like OS, use its file manager or terinal equivalent to check that.

Comment: @underscore_d Yes it returns `-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 356 Sep 1 08:40 vendor/bin/phinx` when i execute that command

So how do i run it as root is the question

Comment: You need to add execute permissions in any case, since that is presumably meant to be an executable binary. Since currently anyone can read, probably anyone should be able to execute too. A simple `chmod +x vendor/bin/phinx` should sort that.

Comment: I have ran that command but still get a ``permission denied` error when I run the migration command

Comment: What does `ls` show for the permissions now?

Comment: @underscore_d `-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 356 Sep 1 08:40 vendor/bin/phinx*` and the vendor/bin/phinx is green

Comment: Pass. I would expect to see `x`s in there and the executable not to be highlighted. I would recommend mentioning what OS, shell, etc you are using and see if anyone else knows.

Comment: @underscore_d `DigitalOcean Droplets are Linux-based virtual machines (VMs) that run on top of virtualized hardware. Each Droplet you create is a new server you can use, either standalone or as part of a larger, cloud-based infrastructure. DigitalOcean Droplets are managed using a terminal and SSH`